# mysql group by only date and count how many results

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by

I have a sample table name (info) in mysql database as follows:

```
id       dateAdded

----------------------------

1        2013-12-24 03:03:19

2        2013-12-24 03:04:19

3        2013-12-24 03:06:14

4        2013-12-24 03:07:23

5        2013-12-25 03:04:19

6        2013-12-26 03:02:19

7        2013-12-26 03:03:19
```

I have another table name (error) as follows:

```
id        date

----------------------------

11        2013-12-24 03:03:19

22        2013-12-24 03:04:19

33        2013-12-25 03:06:14

53        2013-12-25 03:04:19

62        2013-12-26 03:02:19
```

I want to COUNT how many ids from the two tables (info and error) with the same dates , so the result out will be :

```
date             countinfo       counterror

----------------------------------------

2013-12-24       4              2

2013-12-25       1              2

2013-12-26       2              1
```

Please if you could help me out with the Mysql query

Comment: This is something that may be easier in PHP.  Just select the rows you want, iterate through them, and increment an associate array of `'date' => 'count'`.

Comment: cant i have it in mysql?

Comment: Im writing a query, will take a bit as i need to insert them all into my database.....

Comment: @user3150060 please confirm the answer as correct if it worked. That is how SO works. So when someone has the same issue as you, can easily see what the correct solution is. Thank you.

Comment: yes i marked as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try, maybe it can be written in a better way but this gives the desired output.

```
SELECT
DATE(Sub.dateadded) as `Date`,
(   SELECT count(id) 
    FROM test.info 
    WHERE DATE(info.dateadded)=DATE(Sub.dateAdded)) as `CountInfo`,
(   SELECT count(id) 
    FROM test.`error` 
    WHERE DATE(`error`.`date`)=DATE(Sub.dateAdded)) as `ErrorInfo`
FROM
(
SELECT `date` as dateadded 
from test.`error`
UNION SELECT  dateadded 
FROM test.info
) Sub
GROUP BY Date(Sub.dateadded)
```

Notice that my database name used here is `test`, change that to your database name.

Since the date field is from different tables, you must `UNION` them in a subquery so that you can get the relevant dates. Then from there a simple subquery in the select is executed with the dateparameter.

In the future, try to **name your tables with names that is not a datatype or function** name etc, then the **`** is not needed to wrap the database,table,column names

EDIT

If you want specific dates, just make use of `WHERE`.

Add this line before the `GROUP BY`

```
WHERE DATE(Sub.dateadded) IN ('2013-12-24','2013-12-25')
```

If you want between a time span you can do this

```
WHERE DATE(Sub.dateadded) BETWEEN '2013-12-24' AND '2013-12-30'
```

This will give the dates available between 24-30 of December.

Comment: When you join on a subquery, you must give it a name. you can call it Susan if you want. But then you have to write Susan.dateAdded in the subquery. Its so that the database knows where to look

Comment: im getting repeated results?

Comment: wow, i forgot to add the `GROUP BY`. Check the update

Comment: Great! You can then set it as correct answer.

Comment: how would I make the result from this date to the other date

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: like i want to show results from 2013-12-24 to 2013-12-25 only for eaxmple

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please rename the table name that I have provided.

Info : Join both table get the count of distinct Id

```
    select Date(dateadded) as datepart, 
    count(distinct(infotable.id)) as countInfo, 
    count(distinct(errortable.id)) as counterror from infotable inner join errortable
    on Date(infotable.dateadded)=Date(errortable.date)
    group by datepart
```

Comment: It should be a `left join`, even so, this means that same dates must appear in the 2 different tables which they dont so this will miss dates if it only resides in 1 of the tables.

Comment: it worked but it didnt give me all the results?

Comment: Thats beacuse for this to work all dates must be in both tables. That is why a UNION is needed to make this work

Answer (score -1):

Try this for a pure MySQL approach:

```
SELECT dateAdded, COUNT(*) as count_info FROM info GROUP BY dateAdded;
SELECT date, COUNT(*) as count_error FROM error GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: the column name is dateadded in info table

Comment: so you mean I need 2 select statments to do this , I can't do it with one Select?

Comment: You will have to use a subquery with union i think.